# What is the monster under my bed saying?

Tags: unidentified-falling-objects

After completing some objectives on World 5, I came across a shadowy figure who speaks in symbols. After rescuing them, they promptly took up residence under my bed.

What is this creature saying to me? Do the symbols actually mean anything?

[image: monster speaking in symbols]